# How to conditionally redirect and serve HTML with assets at the same time

Tags: http, go

### Problem

When I want to serve static HTML, the assets (CSS, JavaScript) MIME-type is also `text/html`, which leads to an error.

### Approach

Inside `./assets/` is an `index.html`, CSS and JavaScript files.

```
const rootHtml = "./assets/index.html"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))
}

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if false {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/other-route/, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    } else {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, rootHtml) // This should handle the index.html and all other resources
    }
}
```

Assets directory:

```
assets/
|-- js/
|-- css/
|-- index.html
```

Comment: Use [`http.FileServer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) for assets, in the docs there's also an example.

Comment: @mkopriva I tried that, but it returns nothing to the browser: `http.FileServer(http.Dir(rootHtml))`

Comment: rootHtml is not a directory, it points to a file, so your FileServer will serve only that file, hence the mime being always text/html.

Comment: Still not working. I set `const rootHtml = "./assets"` and `http.FileServer(http.Dir(rootHtml))` at the else branch.

Comment: What else branch, take a look at the docs' example. Don't invoke the FileServe inside a handler for each request. You should instantiate it once and register it like in the example.

Comment: This is the exact problem I have. I don't want a global registration. It could be possible that there is a redirect before serving the static resources (the if branch in my code). The example just shows how to register a single handler for all request at `"/"`, which is not the case here.

Comment: Use either a middleware wrapper around the FileServer that does the branching, or use your initial approach but instead of passing a constant to ServeFile, construct the filepath from the request path. Or create yourself a FileServer without registering it, make it global or accessible only to the interested handlers, and then the root handler would invoke the FileServer via its ServeHTTP.

Comment: Have you tried `http.ServeFile(w, r, "./assets/")` in your else branch?